# How to maintain consistency of column name (Java + jsp) using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, consistency

I have this POJO:

```java
Place.class:

@Entity
@Table(name="place")
public class Place {
    @Id @Column(name="idPlace")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="descr")
    private String description;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Into the Dao implementation if I want to filter by place description (for example) I add a Restriction:

```java
getSession().createCriteria(Place.class).add(Restrictions.like("description", "description-filter-value"));
```

Moreover if into the view (example: create.jsp) I want to refer to the description column I write an input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="description" />
```

If in the future I need (for various reasons) to **rename** the field `description` I should be find all the references into the project to the labels "description", both Java and jsp, and rename them; too ugly and boring.

There is a way to write this code in a *consistent* way?

I think to add a static field into `Place.java`:

```java
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
```

and change the previous code to:

```java
getSession().createCriteria(Place.class).add(Restrictions.like(Place.DESCRIPTION, "description-filter-value"));
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="<%=Place.DESCRIPTION%>" />
```

but I would know if exists a batter way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on projects which use static String like the following - as you suggested:

```
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
```

These were however only used to access domain model properties in the Data access tier rather than in the presentation tier. Personally I find it rather ugly.

To ensure consistency between Domain and Data Access tier you could have a look at using the Criteria API and the JPA Metamodel which allows for robust type-safe querying: as your domain model changes, the metamodel should also update automatically to reflect these changes.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/metamodel.html

It is not something I have really used as I find QueryDSL and its simlar strongly typed Metamodel based queries much simpler to use. So this would be an alternative to the JPA Criteria API that might be worth looking at. For example if I have the following where QBooking is a MetaModel 'Query Object' auto-generated by QueryDSL any changes to the domain model (e.g. forename renamed to firstname) are automatically reflected in the Query Object:

```
QBooking.booking qb = QBooking.booking ;
bookingRepository.findAll(qb.accommodation.holiday.eq(holiday).and(
                   qb.status.eq(BookingStatus.CONFIRMED)), qb.skillLevel.level.asc(),
                                qb.user.surname.asc(), qb.user.forename.asc())
```

None of this ensures consistency between the presentation tier and your domain model of course, however I find that in reality the renaming of fields (if you have given the naming of them in the first place a modicum of thought) tends to occur fairly infrequently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that I don't add another library (QueryDSL) into the project, I wouldn't obtain the double of classes (Place and QPlace). For the moment I write the ugly code <%=Place.DESCRIPTION%> into the presentation tier, so if someone decides to rename a property Eclipse instantly inform that there is a compilation error.